# SQL Server Query does not execute with variable, but does with hard-coded value

Tags: sql-server, variables, while-loop, iteration

I have a very simple problem, however I can't see the solution...

My query:

```
DECLARE @DAY INT, @WAITFORVAL VARCHAR(8),
        @ITERATION INT, @ROWCOUNT INT, @TOTALROWS INT

SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW
SET @DAY = 0
SET @WAITFORVAL = '00:00:01'
SET @ITERATION = 0
SET @ROWCOUNT = 0
SET @TOTALROWS = 0

WHILE @DAY > -1 
BEGIN 
  WITH dupl AS
  (SELECT row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3
                        ORDER BY id) rn,
                                     id,
                                     col1,
                                     col2,
                                     col3
   FROM dbo.myTable
   WHERE col4 = 'heartbeat'
     AND col3 < DATEADD(DAY, @DAY, (DATEADD(HOUR, - 0 + DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETDATE(), GetUTCDate()), GetUTCDate())))
     AND col3 > DATEADD(DAY, @DAY, (DATEADD(HOUR, - 24 + DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETDATE(), GetUTCDate()), GetUTCDate())))
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM dupl
  WHERE rn > 1 PRINT 'Iteration: ' + CAST(@ITERATION AS VARCHAR) + ' Day: ' + CAST(@DAY AS VARCHAR) + ' Count: ' + CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS VARCHAR) + ' Total :' + CAST(@TOTALROWS AS VARCHAR)

  SET @DAY = @DAY - 1
  SET @ITERATION = @ITERATION + 1 

  WAITFOR DELAY @WAITFORVAL 
END
```

So, what my query does (or should do), is select all duplicated heartbeats in myTable per day (I will replace the SELECT * with DELETE if it is working) and print the results. Please ignore the `DATEADD(HOUR...` part, this is due to a very weird bug in our system and is too difficult to explain; the important part is the `DATEADD(DAY...` part (DAY, not HOUR).

The query will take forever to execute, and I canceled it after 5 minutes (forgot it was running). When I change the following parts (it's in there twice):

```
DATEADD(DAY, @DAY, (DATEADD(HOUR...
```

To

```
DATEADD(DAY, 0, (DATEADD(HOUR...
```

The query will run in a few seconds, print the result of the first iteration, and stop (since @DAY will be lowered by 1, making the `WHILE` stop).

So, as soon as I change the value from a variable to a hardcoded INT, the query fails to execute (at least in a normal time). I simply fail to understand why, as I have created a similar query but way less complex, which executes perfectly with a variable. So I'm thinking, it must be dueue to the complex `WHERE` clause, or the `WITH` part, but what it is exactly...

Anyone has a suggestion? I tried casting the `@DAY` variable, tried moving the minus outside the variable, ...

---

Simple query that does execute, of course:

```
DECLARE @my_var INT
SET @my_var = 1

WHILE @my_var < 10
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(@my_var) *
    FROM dbo.myTable

    SET @my_var = @my_var + 1
END
```

Does anyone see why my "complex" query can't work with a variable?

Comment: Is the execution plan different? Does adding `option (recompile)` help?

Comment: I poked bogus values into a table myTable...works fine here. Execution time is only affected by waitfor delay - tested Sql Server 2012 and 2014